# a file cannot be deleted and copy and move do not work in C# VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to copy a file in same folder from C# VS2013 on win7.

```
 string myFile = @"C:\Temp\MyFile.txt"
 if (File.Exists(myFile))
 {
       File.Delete(myFile);
 }
 File.Move(myFileSource, myFile);
```

I got error:

```
Additional information: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
```

I checked the folder and found that the file "myFile.txt" is still there after deleting.

If i used:

```
  File.Copy(myFileSource, myFile, true);
```

Error:

```
  Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\Temp\myFile.txt' is denied.
```

Why ? thanks

Comment: Does some other part of your program still have "MyFile.txt" open?

Comment: It is windows 7 that is the issue, not Visual Studio.

Comment: working in c drive have security issue try in other drive or run your exe file with administrator access and test again

Comment: If you step through the code, is the file actually deleted after the `File.Delete` line has been run?

Comment: No, the file is still there after deleting.

Answer (score -2):

Run visual studio as administrator. It's likely a security issue related to UAC.

You may also want to consider writing the file to somewhere where is will work for all such as:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

Comment: for short question or answer use comment ;)